# How would you get this done with Telerik asp.net mvc extensions? accordion, tabs and ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, telerik, partial-views

I know this probably is a fairly complicated question but... heres my case:
I want to build my UI using teleriks jquery ui extensions.

My idea was to create a sidebar with an accordion and the main content with tabs.
The accordion having as content a list of links. Each link mapping to correspond to an item of the accordion.
For instance:

My accordion has
Users
     Create
     Delete

Companies
     Create
     Delete

So if I either click on Users->Create or Users->Delete I would get a tab with those two elements.... 
Here again comes the point that my question seems general.. Im just looking for some reccomendations on how to get this done.... what code would you put on Views? what data to pass between Views and what to put on Shared Views....
Keep in mind that Users and Companies are each a Controller...

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried anything? Can you show us your existing code?

Comment: Yes, sure... right now I have a main.aspx and a sidebar.aspx page inside my shared views folder... the telerik extensions provide example for looping to dynamically create items.. and I have... but only primitive loops like this:

Comment: As you can see... there is a way to dinamycally create items... but I cant figure out an efficient way of passing this data from the controller....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
  <%
    Html.jQuery().Tab()
        .Name("tab")     
        .Items(parent => {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    var x = i; //
                    parent.Add()
                        .Text("Item " + x)    
                        .LoadContentFrom(Url.Action("AjaxView","Home"));
                }
            }
        )
        .Render();
 %>
```